# pgadmin4 1.3 raises CSV export broken

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I installed pgadmin4 1.3 (in a docker container) and everything is working fine except CSV exports.

I filled in *Binary Paths* properly in *Preferences* but it is still not working. I have no error message. When I click the CSV export icon nothing happens.

Here is my config:

- Python version : 2.7.12
- Postgresql version : 9.5
- Pgadmin version : 4.1.3
- Ubuntu 16.04

If someone has the same issue and hopefully knows how to solve it can you please help ?

Thanks !

Comment: We (community ) have fixed this issue in 1.5. So you don't need make modifications in ../pgadmin4/pgadmin/utils/driver/psycopg2/__init__.py file.  See issues 2253, 2314, 2360 at https://redmine.postgresql.org/versions/48

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the culprit !

I had a look to /var/log/apache2/errors.log and saw an `UnicodeEncodeError` during CSV creation. Error came from this file :

`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pgadmin4/pgadmin/utils/driver/psycopg2/__init__.py`

Line 651, the CSV writer was broken when writing special characters like accentuated characters (I am using Python 2, I guess I would not have had the issue with Python 3):

`csv_writer.writerows(results)`

Eventually I solved it by using the `unicodecsv` library :

- `pip install unicodecsv`
- line 22: replaced `import csv` with `import unicodecsv as csv`
- line 647: replaced `csv.DictWriter(res_io, fieldnames=header, delimiter=str(','), quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)` with `csv.DictWriter(res_io, encoding='utf-8', fieldnames=header, delimiter=str(','), quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)`

Hope it might help other people while this encoding bug is not fixed !

Comment: We (community) have fixed this issue in 1.5. So you don't need make modifications in ../pgadmin4/pgadmin/utils/driver/psycopg2/__init__.py file.  See issues 2253, 2314, 2360 at https://redmine.postgresql.org/versions/48